# Magento2 : How to load quote item option by id?

Tags: magento2, quote, option

In a module under Magento 1.9. I was loading quote item option using

```
$_quoteOption = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->load($Option_id);
```

I would like to do the same thing under magento2 but I do not manage to find which class / function to use (`\Magento\Sales\Model\Quote\...` does not exist)

I am in a controller triggered by a button in customer account order view

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Option` class.

```
protected $quoteItemOption;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\OptionFactory $quoteItemOption
)
{
    $this->quoteItemOption = $quoteItemOption;
    ......
}
```

In your execute method, we can use `$this->quoteItemOption->create()->load($optionId);`

Currently, I cannot find another way, I tried with `Factory` and `load` way.

My Magento version is 2.1.5.